# How to put colon after the end of the text

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
var x = "Total12";
```

i need to put after text colon, so the output would be like this

```
var x = "Total:12";
```

How can i do it with Regex?

Comment: Look at the `String.prototype.replace()` method and the options available when passing a regular expression. Hint: the replacement could be `"$1:$2"`. The regex should be simple enough to write.

Comment: ^ that -> `x.replace(/(\D+)/, '$1:')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `/\D+/g,`, for non decimal characters and replace it with the matched string and `:`.

```js
console.log("Total12".replace(/\D+/g, '$&:'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Total12";
var firstDigit = str.match(/\d/);
//returns the first number which is a character
var indexed = str.indexOf(firstDigit)
//find the numberical index;

var finalString = str.substring(0, indexed) + ":" + str.substring(indexed, str.length)
```